# How do I use the Cavalieri principle?

Tags: integration

> I need to use the Cavalieri Principle for the following set: $$C=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2\leq 1, \,\,\,y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$$

First note that $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-dimensional Lebesgue measure for $1\leq i\leq 3$-

I rewrote the set as $$C=\{(x,y,z)|-y\leq x\leq y, \,\,\,y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$$Now I defined the set $$C_x=\{(y,z)|y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$$We remark that $C_x$ is only a circle with radius 1. Therefore we just know that $\lambda_2(C_x)=\pi$. Then I thought that from the Cavalieri Principle $$\lambda_3(C)=\int_{-y}^y\pi \,\,\,\,d\lambda_1(x)=2\pi y$$But I somehow think that this is wrong.

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: In [this document](https://www.sbpm.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Rencontre-de-cylindres.pdf), you have a well documented way to solve your problem. Specially from page 30. The document is in French… but there is so many pictures that it is not an issue.

Comment: Okey thank you but do I need to solve it with $-1\leq y\leq 1$ as below?

Comment: Sorry @mathcounterexamples.net could you explain it to me better, because this document is nice and I think I got an idea but they didn't to it rigorously with $C_x$ ect as we need to do, and I don't understand this. Because somehow I need to get there mathematically and I can't use geometric tools at the exam

Comment: Please help me, I'm really really lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I cut $C$ by plane $\pi_t:y=t\ \ (-1\le t\le1)$, then cross section may be $C(t)={(x,t,z)\mid|x|\le1-t^2, |z|\le1-t^2}$, and area of cross section is $A(t)=4(1-t^2)$.

By Cavalieri Principle, volume of $C$ is $\int_{-1}^1A(t)dt$. So...

$$
V(C)=\int_{-1}^1A(t)dt=\int_{-1}^14(1-t^2)dt=\left[4t-\frac43t^3\right]_{-1}^1=\frac{16}3
$$

Comment: why do you know that $-1\leq y \leq 1$

Comment: furthermore I can't imagine this set $C$ is there a way to draw it or could you upload an image because I can't

Comment: You’re not *stricto sensu* using [Cavalieri’s principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri's_principle?wprov=sfti1) as you’re not comparing two volumes.

Comment: Okey sorry so I only use cavalieris theorem, nevertheless I don't see what @Nightflight did. Could someone explain it to me